# Как убрать пробелы между карточками CardView в RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, cardview

Я первый раз попробовал имплементировать `CardView` в `RecyclerView` и вроде как все работает, но между карточками огромные пробелы, не пойму в чем ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код

XML карточки

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    app:cardElevation="15dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/standard_white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivPersonPhoto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPersonName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivPersonPhoto"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPersonNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvPersonName"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivPersonPhoto"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Вот адаптер

```
public class FriendsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FriendsAdapter.FriendViewHolder> {

List<CardFriend> friends;

public FriendsAdapter(List<CardFriend> friends) {
    this.friends = friends;
}

public static class FriendViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cv;
    TextView friendName;
    TextView friendNumber;
    ImageView friendPhoto;

    FriendViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        friendName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonName);
        friendNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonNumber);
        friendPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPersonPhoto);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return friends.size();
}

@Override
public FriendViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_friend, viewGroup, false);
    FriendViewHolder pvh = new FriendViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FriendViewHolder friendViewHolder, int i) {
    friendViewHolder.friendName.setText(friends.get(i).getFriendName());
    friendViewHolder.friendNumber.setText(friends.get(i).getFriendNumber());
    friendViewHolder.friendPhoto.setImageResource(friends.get(i).getPhotoId());
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
}
```

вот фрагмент

```
public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment {

private static List<CardFriend> friends;

static {
    friends = new ArrayList<>();
    friends.add(new CardFriend("Emma Wilson", "0505343434", R.drawable.ic_add_white_24dp));
    friends.add(new CardFriend("Lavery Maiss", "0505333232", R.drawable.ic_add_white_24dp));
    friends.add(new CardFriend("Lillie Watts", "0504444444", R.drawable.ic_add_white_24dp));
}

public FriendsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);

    RecyclerView rvFriends = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvFriends);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rvFriends.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    FriendsAdapter friendsAdapter = new FriendsAdapter(friends);
    rvFriends.setAdapter(friendsAdapter);

    return rootView;
}

}
```

Разметка Recycler

```
<FrameLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.FriendsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/tool_bar_left_padding" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/background_light"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/background_light"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/background_light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/pager"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: а разметка RecyclerView какая?

Comment: Не видно разметки Recycler'a, но выглядит будто marginBottom 80dp выставлен

Comment: @pavel добавил разметку

Comment: @Asgard добавил разметку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У корневого LinearLayout выставьте `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: Да точно, вот где ошибка. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если мне не изменяет память, то это все из за FloatingButton. То есть он привязан не совсем корректно из-за чего выходит такой пробел. У меня раньше была такая же проблема. Найди в интернете как правильно привязать кнопку и проблема исчезнет